# Takesaki corollary 3.6

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Consider the following fragment from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebra I":[image]

I can't see why the marked equality is true. In particular, I don't see why $\pi(\mathscr{M}'')\subseteq \pi(\mathscr{M})''$.

I think I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit that I don't really follow what Takesaki's logic there. So here is how I know to do it.

Let $S_0\in M'$. For any $x\in\mathscr M$,
$$\tag1
\pi(S_0)\pi(x)=\pi(S_0x)=\pi(xS_0)=\pi(x)\pi(S_0). 
$$
So $\pi(S_0)\in\pi(\mathscr M)'$.

Now let $T\in\pi(\mathscr M)''$. By Proposition 3.5, $T=\pi(T_0)$ for some $T_0\in\mathscr L(\mathfrak H)$. For any $S_0\in\mathscr M'$,
$$
\pi(T_0S_0)=T\pi(S_0)=\pi(S_0)T=\pi(S_0T_0). 
$$
As $\pi$ is faithful, $T_0S_0=S_0T_0$. So $T_0\in\mathscr M''$. This shows that $\pi(\mathscr M)''\subset\pi(\mathscr M'')$.

If we now apply the above to $\mathscr M'$, we get $\pi(\mathscr M')''\subset\pi(\mathscr M')$, which immediately imply
$$\tag2
\pi(\mathscr M')''=\pi(\mathscr M'). 
$$
And applying $(2)$ to $\mathscr M'$, we obtain
$$\tag3
\pi(\mathscr M'')''=\pi(\mathscr M''). 
$$

It now remains to show that "hard" inclusion $\pi(\mathscr M'')\subset\pi(\mathscr M)''$. For this it is good to get some intuition of what's happening. It probably helps to do the case $|I|=2$ explicitly. We have
$$
\pi(x)=\begin{bmatrix} x&0\\0&x\end{bmatrix} . 
$$
One can then check explicitly
$$
\pi(\mathscr M)'=\Big\{\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}:\ a,b,c,d\in\mathscr M'\Big\},
$$
and
$$
\pi(\mathscr M)''=\Big\{\begin{bmatrix} a&\\ &a\end{bmatrix}:\ a\in\mathscr M''\Big\}=\pi(\mathscr M'').
$$
To actually do the general case, it is not hard to show that
$$\tag4
\pi(\mathscr M)'=\big\{X\in\mathscr L(\tilde{\mathfrak H}):\ X_{kj}\in\mathscr M'\ \text{ for all }k,j\big\}. 
$$
As $\mathscr M'''=\mathscr M'$, applying $(4)$ to $\mathscr M''$ we get
$$\tag5
\pi(\mathscr M'')'=\pi(\mathscr M)'. 
$$
Taking commutants,
$$\tag6
\pi(\mathscr M'')''=\pi(\mathscr M)''. 
$$
And now $(3)$ gives us
$$\tag7
\pi(\mathscr M'')=\pi(\mathscr M)''. 
$$

Comment: Thanks! Takesaki sure is a hard book to read for me, but I'm getting a lot out of it.

Comment: Yes, it's not an easy read, and some of the angles he used are not the most mainstream these days. But he does many things in detail that are not easy to find anywhere else. Not the case with the Double Commutant Theorem, though; there are nice accounts in many books.

Comment: I actually liked the part of the Double Commutant theorem. It was just the detail in this question that was not clear to me. The version of the double commutant theorem in Takesaki is the most general one that I encountered so far.